# Efficient method of finding a percentage of time

Tags: c#

Is there an efficient method of calculating the percentage of X from Y, when both data types are `TimeSpan`?

Eg, a basic question would be that `1:00:00` is 50% of `2:00:00`.
What would be an effective method of calculating what percentage is `00:34:23` of `4:12:31`?

Comment: What is `34:23`? That's not a valid time?

Comment: Are you sure X and Y are both a `DateTime`? Would make more sense if both were a `TimeSpan`.

Comment: @mattytommo I guess it is 34 minutes and 23 seconds...

Comment: Convert to TotalSeconds, do the math and convert again to DateTime?

Comment: @mattytommo It is obviously 00:34:23...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

EDIT: As per the comment, the types really are intended to be `TimeSpan` rather than `DateTime`, at which point everything is simple.

When you ask what proportion X is of Y, that's basically division, which is easily implemented on `TimeSpan`:

```
public static double Divide(TimeSpan dividend, TimeSpan divisor)
{
    return (double) dividend.Ticks / (double) divisor.Ticks;
}
```

Sample code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        TimeSpan x = new TimeSpan(0, 34, 23);
        TimeSpan y = new TimeSpan(4, 12, 31);
        Console.WriteLine(Divide(x, y)); // 0.13616 etc, i.e. 13%
    }

    public static double Divide(TimeSpan dividend, TimeSpan divisor)
    {
        return (double) dividend.Ticks / (double) divisor.Ticks;
    }
}
```

Comment: Typo. I meant a `TimeSpan`, I just got a bit muddled up :)

Comment: @Teifi: Right. In which case, see the rest of my answer - and please fix your question. (It's worth reviewing your question carefully before posting it...)

Comment: What is the `Scale` method for?

Comment: @JesseWebb: I think I'd misread the original question - I thought it was asking for operations going in both directions. Will edit.

Answer (score 7):

Use the DateTime.Ticks property. You can find a percentage by subtracting and dividing the DateTime Ticks from eachother. This is the most accurate way.

If you are using just a Time, use the TimeSpan object rather than the DateTime Object.

Comment: What? How do you do this? `DateTime.Ticks` holds gigantic number that is several magnitudes larger then the diff between 1 hour.

Comment: Using `DateTime.Ticks` makes no sense here. One `DateTime` isn't a proportion of another, nor does it make sense to scale on `DateTime` by anything. Fundamentally, this question should be about `TimeSpan`, not `DateTime`.

Comment: It does make sense, it is the most accurate time measurement variable in the .NET framework. It is measured down to one ten-millionth of a second. This makes the percentage more accurate and cleaner. The above answer is using Ticks as well and you posted it. I also labeled both scenarios when using DateTime and TimeSpan. You should know when to use both.

Answer (score 2):

Time is measured in units and any time can be converted to number of that units, and then processed as any other number. Create a `TimeSpan` and take `TotalSeconds` and then do the math.